# Citing a website reference

Tags: ieee, citations

I am attempting to write a paper to IEEE.
I have used a sound file from the website freesounds.org. Is there a particular format for citing the website reference for IEEE journals? I checked the IEEE website. They are showing how to cite a website for an article. Not sure how to do it for the sound file. 
Thanks. :)

Comment: Are you using Bib(La)TeX?

Comment: I had thought this comment went through, but apparently it did not.  Migrate this to Writers.SE - it'll be on-topic there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.york.ac.uk/integrity/ieee.html:

> [nn] D. Fisher, Writer, and T. Baker, Presenter, Doctor Who and the Creature from the Pit [Sound recording]. Bath, UK: BBC Audiobooks, 2009.

Generalizing,

> F. Last, Writer, and F. Laster, Presenter, Title of Work [Sound Recording]. City, Country: Publisher, Year.

If you're using Bib(La)TeX, I would do it like this:

```
@audio{last12,
  author = {Fred Last, Writer and Frank Laster, Presenter},
  title = {Title of Work},
  howpublished = {Sound Recording},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  city = {City, Country},
  year = 2009
}
```

My best stab.

---

If you're using Word (which you really shouldn't be - writing in IEEE, you know better), [there is a style available](http://mikemurko.com/general/ieee-referencing-for-word-2007-2010/).